# LiveData not updating from insert in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I want to propagate repository response to the user as a toast so i put live data listener in my activity on post create method

```
mainViewModel.toast.observe(this) {
            Log.d(TAG, "initViews: $it")
            if (it.notPropagated) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    it.message,
                    if (!it.longToast) Toast.LENGTH_SHORT else Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                mainViewModel.setMessageToPropagated()
            }
        }
```

toast is simple live data created from flow i get from database

```
val toast = mainRepository.getMessage().asLiveData(viewModelWorkerContext)
```

but when I'm trying to change the data in database in other fragment by using insert it never actually update on change, only when I restart application it is getting the stuff from database and respond to the `mainViewModel.setMessageToPropagated()` that changes message to "used" and that triggers livedata no problem.
Here is my DAO:

```
@Dao
interface RoomDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun setMessage(message: SingleTimeUserMessage)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM SingleTimeUserMessage WHERE notPropagated = true LIMIT 1")
    fun getMessageToPropagate(): Flow<SingleTimeUserMessage>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM SingleTimeUserMessage LIMIT 1")
    fun getMessageToPropagated(): SingleTimeUserMessage
}
```

And lastly, providers

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RoomDatabase {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMainDatabase(app: Application): MainDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(app, MainDatabase::class.java, "MainDatabase")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTvDao(database: MainDatabase): RoomDao {
        return database.tvDao()
    }
}
```

I read many topics related to this problem and it was often resolved by making providers return the same instance of database but as far as I know my providers should always return the same instance. Any ideas and help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say you are changing the database from another fragment, does it mean the "toast" fragment is paused?

Comment: toast observer is in activity, it is always active since this application consists from single activity

Comment: What does `mainRepository.getMessage()` look like. By the way, totally unrelated, but probably you want that third DAO function to be `suspend`.

Comment: ```fun getMessage() = room.getMessageToPropagate()``` it is literally pass through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my code that I was not aware works like that. I had useless annotations on all my Repositories

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
```

after removing it everything seems to run great.

Hope this can help someone in future that struggles with similar problems.